# Expressing $ z= \tan2i$ in the form $a + ib$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Given $ z = \tan2i $, express $z$ in the form $a + ib$.

---

I tried this way:

$$ \tan2i = \frac{\sin2i}{\cos2i}=\frac{\frac{e^{-2}-e^{2}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{-2}+e^{2}}{2}} $$

and got stuck with:

$$\frac{e^{-2}-e^{2}}{i\left(e^{-2}+e^{2}\right)}$$

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: multiply top and bottom by $i$ and you are left with a purely imaginary number

Comment: You practically got stuck with the right solution (Lol)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{i}=-i.$ You're pretty much done.

$-i\frac{\frac{1}{e^2}-e^2}{\frac{1}{e^2}+e^2}=-i\frac{1-e^4}{1+e^4}=\frac{e^4-1}{e^4+1}i.$